# XL macro which exposes jpeg files - where are the jpeg files stored

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

Here is the macro which is in the Sheet1 module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim oPic As Picture
    Me.Pictures.Visible = False
    With Range("F1")
        For Each oPic In Me.Pictures
            If oPic.Name = .Text Then
                oPic.Visible = True
                oPic.Top = .Top
                oPic.Left = .Left
                Exit For
            End If
        Next oPic
    End With
End Sub
```

In the work book this is what it looks like:

[image]

How do I gain access to `Me.Pictures`? We'd like to add pictures and delete some of the existing pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this which just uses the third line in your existing code

```
Private Sub MakeAllPicsVisible()
    Me.Pictures.Visible = True
End Sub
```

`Me` refers to the worksheet object the code is in. And each picture appears to be named with the items in the list

To change the picture name, enter a new name via the Name Box (left of Formula bar).